# Changing lookup table name using code first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I am using code first approach for creating database. I have many to many relationship between tewo tables User and Employee. The lookup table which appears in database comes out to be UserEmployee. How can I reverse the order of name of this lookup table i.e. EmployeeUser and what will be the possible implications if I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use fluent API to accomplish it:

```
builder.Entity<Employee>()
   .HasMany(e => e.Users).WithMany(u => u.Employees)
   .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("EmployeeId")
   .MapRightKey("UserId")
   .ToTable("EmployeeUser"));
```

Comment: I think so too. Is it also possible that the order in which we specify the DBSet for the entity makes the difference. I mean to say, if I specify User before Employee, table created will be UserEmployee and if first Employee and then User then table will be EmployeeUser.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but it might be safe to say that it's probably random, and if the order happens to matter I don't think it's safe to rely on it.